# ListAdapter not change data with notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, listadapter

I have a Fragment with a ListView and ListAdapter, in this Fragment I have an volley method to get some informations of a webservice. These informations I added in a ListView, the problems is when I try change the adapter with others informations, the adapter not change.

When method is executed first time does works, because the Adapter equals null and I do define it, but when I do back to fragment `addToBackStack()` doesn't works. I added in `onResume()` but not work also.

How can I do it ?

**Fragment**

```
public class FormCidadesFrag extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private ListView lvCidades;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private static List<Cidade> lista;
    private CidadesListAdapter cidadeLA;
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName() + "->";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((CustomDrawerLayout)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frm_cidades, container, false);
        lvCidades = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvCidades);
        lvCidades.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // action bar title
        ActionBar actionBar = ((CustomDrawerLayout)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Guia Store");

        return  view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getAllCidades();
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


    /** retorna todas as cidades */
    private void getAllCidades(){
        progress = new CustomProgressDialog().getCustomProgress("Buscando cidades...", getView().getContext());
        progress.show();
        ApplicationController app = new CidadeDAO().getAllCidades(new CidadeAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void getAllCidades(List<Cidade> list) {
                if(!list.isEmpty()){
                    lista = list;
                    if(cidadeLA == null){
                        //works
                        cidadeLA = new CidadesListAdapter(lista, getView().getContext());
                        lvCidades.setAdapter(cidadeLA);
                    }else{
                        //not works
                        cidadeLA.changeList(lista);
                    }
                }
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
        CustomVolleySingleton.getInstance(getView().getContext()).addToRequestQueue(app);
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class CidadesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private List<Cidade> list;
    private Context context;

    public CidadesListAdapter(List<Cidade> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //change adapter
    public void changeList(List<Cidade> list){
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Could you try to call changeList with the variable `list` instead of `lista`? You're passing the same list to your adapter as it already has, which might be the cause of the not working `notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged` will check if you have called clear, add, delete method when update data. So you must used the method mentioned instead of assign list `this.list = list`

```
//change adapter
public void changeList(List<Cidade> list){
    this.list.clear();
    for(Cidade item: list){
        this.list.add(item);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(cidadeLA == null){
                    //works
                    cidadeLA = new CidadesListAdapter(lista, getView().getContext());
                    lvCidades.setAdapter(cidadeLA); 
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else{
                    //not works
                    cidadeLA.changeList(lista);
// notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

from your code ,

1) First if condition is working so, 
  after setAdapter you need to call the notifyDataSetChanged().

2) Agree with @edisonthk you need to move the notifyDataSetChanged() out of your method.

3) Put Log.d(); to check it seriously you will get null for first condition otherwise your data never fill into adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some callbacks like this

```
    public class CidadesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private List<Cidade> list;
        private Context context;

        public CidadesListAdapter(List<Cidade> list, Context context) {
            this.list = list;
            this.context = context;
        }

        //change adapter
        public void changeList(List<Cidade> list){
            this.list = list;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public Object getItem(int pos)
        {
          return list.get(pos);
        }

        public int  getCount()
        { 
          return list.size();
        }
}
```